# What programming language was Windows written in?

Tags: windows

Just out of curiosity I want to know what language was used to write Windows itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> We use almost entirely C, C++, and C# for Windows. Some areas of code are hand tuned/hand written assembly.

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowshpcacademic/thread/65a1fe05-9c1d-48bf-bd40-148e6b3da9f1

Answer (score 8):

[Answered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380988/what-programming-language-was-windows-vista-programmed-in/380997#380997)

> Well, the Windows kernel is still almost entirely C. However, there are different aspects that use C++, say some parts of the shell and so forth. The core is C. Other languages, perhaps even .NET might be used in some corners for certain applications but C is the OS language of choice in Windows.